# Move Search Bar (Magento 2)

Tags: magento2, php, layout, xml, home-page

I want to move the search bar from right to the center of the homepage using xml.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <move element="block.search" destination="header-wrapper" after="logo" />
```

We have to add this in `default.xml` file

and then change the `css` accordingly, after that it will work fine.

Comment: <move element="block.search" destination="header-wrapper" after="logo" />

Answer (score 0):

If you're using magento2.3 then the correct file path is given below.

app/design/frontend/Vendor_Name/Theme_Name/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
         <move element="top.search" destination="header-wrapper" after="logo" />
</body>
</page>
```

And don't forget to flush magento cache.

Answer (score -3):

Add this in css file,

```
.block-search{

         float:left

         }
```

Comment: We have to do it using xml.